# Access a DynamoDB table from another account in another region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Is it possible to have Lambda access a DynamoDB table in a Chinese AWS account from another account from a non-China region like us-west-2 or us-east-1?

Example:

Account 1, Region: us-east-1 Lambda function lives here that needs to access DynamoDB

Account 2, Region: cn-north-... DynamoDB table lives here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are currentlh three separate and independent partitions in AWS.

There's `aws` (the one commonly thought of and referred to as "AWS"), `aws-cn` (China) and `aws-us-gov` (GovCloud US).

There appears to be no connection whatsoever among the three partitions -- even the "Global" namespace of S3 buckets is only global *within* each partition.

Operationally, it is as if there are three completely autonomous and independent "copies" of AWS.  As such, there is no cross-account IAM access possible, because the partitions seem entirely unaware of each other.

You should be able to use IAM user credentials obtained from the China account to access resources in the `aws-cn` partition *from anywhere*.  There should be no impediment to this, since the [DynamoDB endpoint in cn-north-1](https://dynamodb.cn-north-1.amazonaws.com.cn) is accessible directly from the Internet.  You'd need to pass these credentials to the DynamoDB client, rather than using the Lambda function's role credentials.

Comment: That sounds promising. Do you have any recommendations on how to obtain the needed credentials and how to reference and use these credentials from Lambda? 
I'm having trouble finding solutions online that don't expose the credentials in a way that seems a bit unsafe.

Comment: You'll have to create the credentials the usual way, but see [Create a Lambda Function Using Environment Variables To Store Sensitive Information](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-env_console.html) for storing them encrypted-at-rest.  They'll be decrypted and dropped into the environment when the Lambda containers are spawned, so that your code can access them and pass them to the DynamoDB client.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access DynamoDB table from one region to another. When you use your SDK, update the region to `cn-north` that should take care from there.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'cn-north'});
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB();
dynamodb.batchGetItem(params, function (err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

If you are using another account, create a separate role (AssumeRole for another account) and add it to Lambda. You can also access with separate AccessKey and SecretKey. But Role is recommended.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_permissions-to-switch.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: While this *would* work great, it looks like I can't create a role for the non-CN account to Assume.

At the point where I need to create a role on Account 2, if I try to specify a non-CN account as the trusted entity, it fails ('invalid principal"). But if I try to specify another CN account, it lets me create the role. (Note CN realms can't live on non-CN accounts)

So it doesn't look like it will be as simple as switching between other regions due to CN's "Great Wall": https://fastretailing.github.io/blog/2015/09/29/AWS-ChinaBeijing-Region-Tips.html

Comment: In that case, instead of assuming a role, you would need to be provided actual credentials in the other account. (An IAM User, rather than an IAM Role.) It's probably due to the separation between the CN regions and the other regions.

Answer (score 0):

There are public API addresses for each AWS Service you can use them and sign the requests on your own to send data accross different accounts.